# Specify the encoding in xml file

Tags: c#

i have an Dataset where i am converting it into an xml file, now i need to specify encoding="UTF-8" in xml file, i am using an vs2003, 
pls let me know the  syntax  how  to  do it.

my code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbconn);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter cmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from employee", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            cmd1.Fill(ds);
            string strFileName = @"E:\Diff2.xml";

            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();  
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memStream, Encoding.Default); 
            ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

thanks
prince

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memStream, Encoding.Default);
ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

// Return XML string

return Encoding.Default.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer());
```

Comment: i  tried like this  but  no  file seems  to be  getting created